# Рекурсивный поиск в Vim с помощью плагина Grep

Tags: vim

ОС: windows 7 x64.
Установил плагин [Grep](https://github.com/vim-scripts/grep.vim). Скачал указаные в плагине файлы grep и findutils.

Прописал в файле конфигурации вим пути к grep:

```
let Grep_Path             = 'e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe'
let Fgrep_Path            = 'e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\fgrep.exe'
let Egrep_Path            = 'e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\egrep.exe'
let Grep_Find_Path        = 'e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\find.exe'
let Grep_Xargs_Path       = 'e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\xargs.exe'
```

Перезагружаю вим. Команда Grep работает. Но рекурсивный поиск (Rgrep) выдает следующее:

```
|| [Search results for pattern: RcbModules]
|| 
|| e:\RsBank\web\Report\Rcb>e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\find.exe "e:\RsBank\web\Report\Rcb" -type d ( -name RCS -o -name CVS -o -name SCCS ) -prune -o -type f ! -name *~ ! -name *,v ! -name s.* ( -name *.cs ) -print0   | e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\xargs.exe -0 e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe  -s -n -- RcbModules NUL 
|| e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\find.exe: <ef><f3><f2><e8> <e4><ee><eb><e6><ed><fb> <e1><fb><f2><fc> <ef><e5><f0><e5><e4> <e2><fb><f0><e0><e6><e5><ed><e8><e5><ec>
|| Usage: e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\find.exe [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

Из командной строки отрабатывает правильно и выдает результат.

```
e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\find.exe "e:\RsBank\web\Report\Rcb" -type d ( -name RCS -o -name CVS -o -name SCCS ) -prune -o -type f ! -name *~ ! -name *,v ! -name s.* ( -name *.cs ) -print0   | e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\xargs.exe -0 e:\Program\Installed\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe  -s -n -- RcbModules NUL
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Работает с grep\find из cygwin. Но нужно обязательно прописать

```
let Grep_Shell_Quote_Char = "'"
```